# Swift UICollectionView not calling method didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to create a custom collectionView but the method `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is not working for some reason.

I added the `UICollectionViewDelegate` into the Controller, but is not working.
here some code:

```
//
//  PacotesViagensViewController.swift
//  Alura Viagens
//
//  Created by Guilherme Golfetto on 04/01/21.
//

import UIKit

class PacotesViagensViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
            
    @IBOutlet weak var pacotesViagem: UICollectionView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pesquisarViagens: UISearchBar!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelContadorPacotes: UILabel!
    let listaComTodasViagens:Array<Viagem> = ViagemDAO().retornaTodasAsViagens();
    
    var listaViagens:Array<Viagem> = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listaViagens = listaComTodasViagens;
        pacotesViagem.dataSource = self
        pacotesViagem.delegate = self;
        pesquisarViagens.delegate = self;
        self.labelContadorPacotes.text = self.atualizaContagemLabel();

    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.listaViagens.count;
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let celulaPacote = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celulaPacote", for: indexPath) as! PacoteViagemCollectionViewCell;
        
        let viagem = listaViagens[indexPath.row];
        
        celulaPacote.labelTitulo.text = viagem.titulo;

        return celulaPacote;
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //dividido por dois porque são duas colunas
        let larguraCelula = collectionView.bounds.width / 2;
        return CGSize(width: larguraCelula - 15, height: 160)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("HIIII") //STILL NOT WORKING
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        listaViagens = listaComTodasViagens;
        if searchText != "" {
            // o [c] é para virar case insetivea
            //o [d] é para ignorar a acentuação
            let filtroListaViagem = NSPredicate(format: "titulo contains[c] %@", searchText);
            
            let listaFiltrada:Array<Viagem> = (listaViagens as NSArray).filtered(using: filtroListaViagem) as! Array;
            
            listaViagens = listaFiltrada;
        }
        
        self.labelContadorPacotes.text = self.atualizaContagemLabel();
        pacotesViagem.reloadData();
    }
    
    func atualizaContagemLabel() -> String {
        return listaViagens.count == 1 ? "1 pacote encontrado" : "\(listaViagens.count) pacotes encontrado";
    }

}
```

I'm pretty new in Swift development and I don't know what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:

Add all the Controller Code

Comment: now the collectionview has some items in running?

Comment: yes. it comes from another class. I don't see your point

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. The delegate pattern is right.
As I think, you have to implement datasource functions so that the collection view can have some items.
According to the current code, there is not item in collection view.
So didSelectItemAt event can't occur now.
Please reference following code.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.textLabel.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.item + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Harry, I posted now all the code from controller. you'll see that all those methods are here